# How to make mutable pointer to field of node of tree and mutate it?

Tags: rust, borrowing

I want to find some node in the tree and I need a pointer to the container of nodes: `&mut Vec<Node>`

```
struct Node {
    c: Vec<Node>,
    v: i32,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(u: i32, n: Node) -> Node {
        let mut no = Node {
            c: Vec::new(),
            v: u,
        };

        no.c.push(n);

        no
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Node::new(1,
        Node::new(2,
        Node::new(3,
        Node::new(4,
        Node::new(5,
        Node {
            c: Vec::new(),
            v: 6,
        })))));

    let mut p: &mut Vec<Node> = &mut a.c;

    while p.len() > 0 {
        p = &mut p[0].c;
    }

    p.push(Node {
        c: Vec::new(),
        v: 7,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a temporary variable to calm down the borrow checker:

```
while p.len() > 0 {
    let t = p;
    p = &mut t[0].c;
}
```

Or:

```
while p.len() > 0 {
    p = &mut {p}[0].c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can not understand, why lifetime in rust ends with brackets { }, I think, lifetime should end then this variable uses last time.

Comment: @J.Jerk lifetime is a time limits of a variable which begins from allocation and ends with deallocation. Deallocation process takes place when the variable goes out of its scope. [Read more](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#thinking-in-scopes)

Comment: @J.Jerk This is not lifetime issue. Borrow checker thinks that `p` is mutably borrowed by itself here: `p=&mut p[0].c`. After that `p` is locked, you can't do anything  anymore with it. Replacing `p` with temporary variable allows to avoid self-locking.

Comment: It's when I see such work-arounds that I realize the compiler could benefit from some tweaking on lifetimes :D